# How to open .BNDL files

Tags: windows, mac, file-extension

I want to edit a .BNDL file in windows 7 but when I open it with notepad or Microsoft Office 2010, I get a file with weird characters.

Is there a way to edit this file in windows?

Regards

Comment: Where did this file come from? The most common use for .BNDL files is [Mac-specific](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/bundle).

Comment: https://fileinfo.com/extension/bndl

Answer (score 0):

As far as my research shows, a BNDL file can be one of two things:

1. A game bundle file (used for storing resources such as sounds, textures, etc. used by a computer game)
2. A MAC OS "plugin file" for programs. I don't think it would do any good trying to open this on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[Sinni800's answer](https://superuser.com/a/507089/23133) has it right, but he didn't post any software to open this file

For first file type (Game Bundle File) you can use **EA Layer 3 Decoder**

You should try using website like [FileExntesion.org](http://www.fileextension.org/BNDL), you can find there actual list of software to support unknown file extensions.